# How to use the dsm( ) Devel function to print the $form array of my form?

Tags: debugging

I want to use the `dsm()` function of the Devel module to print the `$form` array of a form, where the `form_id` is `search_theme_form`. How to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Start a custom module, insert this code:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function foo_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_theme_form') {
    dpm($form);
  }
}
```

Also, you might want to use dpm() over dsm() since the latter is a legacy function.

Comment: @sokratis you can also download my [simple module for forms developping](https://github.com/mojzis/fapidev) - it adds the `dpm($form_state)` even after submitting

Comment: is this still accurate?

Answer (score 3):

```
function THEME_form_search_theme_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state){

krumo ($form); // you can use DSM as well here

}
```

Replace THEME with your theme name and put that in your template.php, if you want to do that from a module then replace THEME by your module name and put that funciton in your .module file

Answer (score 2):

Use [drupal_retrieve_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_retrieve_form) to get the structured form array:

```
$form_state = array();
dsm(drupal_retrieve_form('search_theme_form', &$form_state));
```